# Ordering a query using SUPQuery on iOS

Tags: ios, sup, supquery

I know there is a way to define the order we want things in a query, but although I know it, I am not able to use it. In my example I have the following:

```
    SUPQuery *query=[SUPQuery getInstance];
    [query select:@"s.fname, s.lname"];
    [query from:@"Sales_order" :@"s"];
    [query orderBy:@"s.lname" : 0];
```

The input paramenters for the orderBy are:

```
[query orderBy:(SUPString*) :(SUPInt)];
```

I don't know what else to try for those two fields, does anyone has some clue? Thanks.

P.S: Do you know where I could find a resource center/blog, etc where I could see some examples implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to figure it out:

```
[query orderBy:@"s.lname" : [SUPSortOrder DESCENDING]];
```